# how to multidimesional array as follows in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, multidimensional-array

I want to make array 
like this

```
var ImageArray = [
             {image:"/image1.jpg"},
             {image:"/image1.jpg"},
             {image:"/image1.jpg"}
             ]
```

I want to make above structure of array from div containing images using each function of jquery.

so that I can retrieve it like `ImageArray[index].image`

Comment: Can you provide the associated HTML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var ImageArray = [];

$('div img').each(function(){
   ImageArray.push({image:this.src});
});
```

this `div` part of the selector should be altered to match the div you want to use as the container..

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`jQuery.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to do it in a single call, without having to declare a separate array, e.g.:

```
var ImageArray = $('div img').map(function(i,img) {
  return {image:this.src};
});
```

Comment: Remember to use .get() at the end to retrieve the raw array then assign it to a variable.

Comment: @John Strickler, no need to use `get()` in this case since map returns an array of the objects returned by the callback function.  But the assignment is a good idea, that makes the intent a little more clear.

Comment: I thought it was an array wrapped in a jQuery object? I may be wrong but I believe .get() will return the actual array ("unwrapping it").

Comment: @John Strickler: hmm, after testing it does appear that the returned array has a "get" method which "returns a 'clean' array" (as opposed to a jQuery tainted one?) so I guess using `get()` is fine but not strictly necessary.  I wonder what the pros/cons of that are...

Answer (score 0):

```
var ImageArray = [];
$('div.images').children('img').each( function() {
  ImageArray.push({ image: this.src }) // or $(this).attr('src')
} );
```