# Reason for .get() without index in jQuery API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Let's say that I've got a page which extracts some image sources like so:

```
<div id="d">
  <img src="foo.gif"/>
  <img src="bar.gif"/>
  <img src="gah.gif"/>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var srcs = $('div#d > img').map(function(){return this.src});
  // srcs => ['foo.gif', 'bar.gif', 'gah.gif']
</script>
```

Note that `srcs` is not a JavaScript Array but an array-like object; we know this because of the fact that we can make jQuery API calls on objects returned by the selector and the fact that `srcs.constructor != Array`.

The jQuery API provides a [`.get()` method](http://api.jquery.com/get/) which, when given no argument, returns a "standard" Array.  Is there a compelling reason to use a standard Array instead of an array-like object or is this method just included for completeness?

**[Edit]**

To put it another way - what are the differences between a JavaScript Array and the array-like object returned by a jQuery selector?

Comment: The quest continues!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253601/how-to-multidimesional-array-as-follows-in-javascript/6253693#6253693

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It allows you to use standard array methods which jQuery doesn't have, such as `push`.

In particular, jQuery objects are intended to be immutable, whereas arrays are not.

Answer (score 1):

Main advantage of `get` is enabling negative indexes like `-1` for getting last element. No argument just gets you the raw unwrapped array of matched elements.